# KendoUI Grid Decimal number column

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a column for weight (in Kg). When the user clicks on it I need to enable them to be able to put in decimal number with 3 places.

The problem I have is at the moment it only allows them to put it in to 2 places, but shows as 3 places. You can type in a number to many decimal places but when it saves it will round it to 2 places.

My column is set up like so:

```
...
{
        field: "weight",
        title: "Weight",
        width: 40,
        format: "n4",
        decimals: 4,
        step: 0.001,
        template: "#= weight.toFixed(3)+'kg' #"
}
...
```

I have tried a few things but none work.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Several questions (afaik):

1. Format in columns is not defined as `n4` but as `{0:n4}`.
2. Formats are not just for the format of the number but might also include some text. Ex: `{0:n4} Kg.`
3. For numeric columns, is not possible to specify attributes as `decimals`, `step` so you should define an editor function.

In addition, I don't understand your problems with decimals and round.

What I suggest is define the columns as:

```
{
    field: "weight",
    title: "Weight",
    width: 40,
    editor: numberEditor,
    format: '{0:n3} Kg.'
}
```

(assuming that you want three decimal precision) and define `numberEditor` as:

```
function numberEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoNumericTextBox({
                format  : "{0:n3}",
                decimals: 3,
                step    : 0.001
            });
}
```