# Kendo Grid numbers truncate to 2 decimal places. How to make it respect what the user entered?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

In this [Kendo Grid demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing), if you edit the numbers under "Units in Stock" and add multiple decimals (try 2.203848), it'll truncate it to 2.20. It looks like that's the default behavior.

And I know that we can specify the decimal format with `{0:n4}`, for example.

But what if the number of decimals is *unknown* or can vary? Is there any way to make the grid use the exact number that the user enters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make this work in a grid, you need to use a custom editor. Set the number of decimals to a high enough number and make sure your field format has enough places. This great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591628/kendoui-grid-decimal-number-column) tweaked a bit solves your problem.

```
function numberEditor(container, options) {
$('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoNumericTextBox({
            decimals: 8,
            step    : 0.01
        });
}

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    navigatable: true,
    pageable: true,
    height: 550,
    toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
    columns: [
        "ProductName",
        { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: 120 },
        { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", format: "{0:0.#########}", width: 120, editor: numberEditor },
        { field: "Discontinued", width: 120 },
        { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: 150 }],
    editable: true
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

The kendo ui grid supports any format that you can use when calling kendo.format() directly.  The documentation for that is available [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/numberformatting).

The format you are looking for is

```javascript
{0:$###,###,###,###,###,###,###,###.##############}
```

You will need to pad that out to however many decimal places you want to support.

Comment: I've tried this out with no luck. Here's a JSFiddle I created. The format is applied to the UnitsInStock column ({0:###.######}) but entering, say 20.238384 returns 20.24. http://jsfiddle.net/dmathisen/ot6tw2nu/

Comment: This only talks about formatting the way the number is displayed. It doesn't affect the behavior when then user user enters a value.